# System settings won't start in Ubuntu

Tags: settings, system-settings, gnome-control-center

My settings didn't work from the new update in my Ubuntu software. Whenever I try to run it, it just doesn't run at all.

When I try to open my settings in my terminal,

```
$ gnome-control-center
```

> ***This was the result*** : *gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries:
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18: unexpected reloc
> type 0x08000006*

I tried reinstalling the gnome control center,tried to create a symbolic link between broken shared libraries but still, I get the same issues. **Any help** on this would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Use Synaptic Manager to install gnome-control-center
Then you can also use it to fix broken packages as well.

I find it (Synaptic) works well when other ways do not. It has helped me fix broken and dependent packages in the past

Comment: Sorry if I am asking much, but can you provide more details on how to fix it as I am just a beginner in using Ubuntu software.

Comment: click the Super key and type synaptic, it should show up in the list. Open it and in the search box type gnome-control-center. When it finds this check the box to install then click Apply. Then it should install the appelet